# Please check this for errors

Tags: php, jquery, curl

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.location.href='http://www.redirectlink.com?ref='+this.href;
        return false;
      });
    </script>
</head>

<?php          
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.14:8081/home/');
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $curl_response;     
?>
```

Should this be working? It curls a page and then when you click on a link on the page it should redirect to http://www.redirectlink.com?ref='+this.href The curling part works but it doesn't redirect. It still takes me to the original url. The jquery-1.6.1.js file is in the same directory as all the other files.

EDIT: Problem fixed. Needed to ready the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect?

Four issues:

1).  You're calling the $('a') selector before the document has loaded.  You won't get any A's.  You'll need to wrap this in document.ready or something similar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //put your script block here.
});
```

2).  You need to encodeUriComponent on this.href.

3).  You seem to be assuming it is a fully-qualified URL, never a relative URL.

4).  If what you're lookng for is a redirect, you'll need to just use a redirect header (CURL isn't necessary):

```
if (array_key_exists('ref', $_GET))
{
  header('Location: '.$_GET['ref']);
  exit;
}
```

Note -- this must go ABOVE any output... basically, move your php block to the very top of the file.

---

Clarification.  Not a redirector at all:

```
if (array_key_exists('ref', $_GET))
{
   echo file_get_contents($_GET['ref'];
}
```

The above block replaces all of your PHP code in 3 easy-to-understand lines.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working as is. This is just part of the code. I have made accounts for the relative urls.

Comment: I just added a clarification to the PHP part... make sure you get that.  : )

Comment: I modified the PHP (issue 4) after you commented.  It didn't have the key check before.  I have no idea what good CURL is to you if you're doing a redirect, so I factored that out.

Comment: Its complicated to explain.. I'm getting a page via curl and then when any link is clicked it redirects and curls that link. Otherwise when links are clicked they go back to the original site

Comment: @Michael: This answer is worthy to accept not mine. The reason is @John has taken time to explain why your thing did not work. Point 2 is also to be noted. I would encourage you (@Michael) to post your answers like @John did and not like mine :)

Comment: So not a redirect at all.  More of an anonymizer.

Of course, that makes sense now, looking at why you need an $('a') interceptor.  You'd simplify the code by using file_get_contents.

Comment: @Mayank - aw.  +1 for you.  : )

Comment: Probably but I'm new to php and I'm trying to achieve something. I've almost there using curl so I'm gonna finish it using curl or it means more hours of trial and error and questions with new commands.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expert at jquery but I believe you need a ready function

```
$.ready(function() {  
   $('a').click(function(e){  
      e.preventDefault();  
      document.location.href='http://www.redirectlink.com?ref='+this.href;  
      return false;  
   });  
});
```

Try above...

Comment: Thank you! It works. Will accept answer once I can :)

Answer (score 1):

also, shouldn't the script start as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

Comment: Preferred but not mandatory, especially in HTML5.  JavaScript is the default language now (like it wasn't before).  : )

Comment: Thanks, i've always used this, so I didn't realize that it is now not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

@Mayank,

Is correct,

do it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.location.href='http://www.redirectlink.com?ref='+this.href;
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole thing like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { [your code] });
```

Answer (score 0):

What's more, I think that

```
e.preventDefault();
```

and

```
return false;
```

have same behavior.